# How to make my regular expression accept zeroes in the input?

Tags: regular-expression

I wrote a regex that accepts numbers between 0 and 999,999,999,999.99. Commas are optional, but, still should accept value not higher than 999999999999.99. I wrote one, but, there are two flaws in it.

```
(^[1-9][0-9,]{0,14}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)
```

1. Accept zeroes. So, 0, 0.00 is valid but, 00 or 00.00 is not valid.
2. Do not accept value higher than 999,999,999,999.99 without commas.

How can I do that? I am testing it with regex101.com pcre(php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test file content:

```
start cmd:> cat file
999,999,999,999.99
999999999999.99
9,999,999,999,999.99
9999999999999.99
0
0.00
00
00.00

grep -E '^(0|0\.[0-9]{1,2}|'\
'[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,?[0-9][0-9][0-9]){0,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|'\
'[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9][0-9][0-9])*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$' file
999,999,999,999.99
999999999999.99
9,999,999,999,999.99
0
0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to validate a number range based on regex, but if you still insist below regex can be used. It does not match if the numbers have comma in it. You can remove comma before doing this regex match.

```
^(:?(?=[1])(10{0,11})|(?=[^0])(\d{1,12})|0)\.[0-9]{1,2}$
```

You can check it out in [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rR4xG2/4).

Comment: If I need to remove commas, your regex doesn't seem to return anything. If I didn't need commas, (^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,11})(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$) seems to be working. But, I need to consider commas as well. Your regex doesn't seem to work with numbers without decimals.